# What can I do with Thorium?

Tags: kittens-game

I just found out I have over 900 Thorium:

[image]

I don't know where I got it from, nor what it does (nor did I know it was in the game). I suppose I got it from some trades and oversaw it.

How can I get Thorium and what can it be used for?

Comment: I dont play the game but I found this on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/kittensgame/comments/58b3t5/what_consumes_thorium/

Comment: @ZeroStack Thanks, though it covers just 1/2 the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you got it, but, usually, [Thorium](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=thorium) would be created from the **Workshop** by processing 250 units of **Uranium**. You first have to unlock it by researching the [Thorium technology](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Technologies#Thorium).

Thorium allows you to build:

- Tectonic (Building, Space)
- Antimatter Fission (Upgrade, Workshop)
- Thorium Reactors (Upgrade, Workshop)
- Thorium Engine (Upgrade, Workshop)

In addition, the Thorium Reactor workshop upgrade will cause Reactors to consume Thorium at the rate of 0.25/tick, which is the only way to create Thorium Consumption.

Comment: how much uranium gives how much Thorium? I can't find thorium in my Workshop tab.

Comment: Thorium is a post space-age item.  It takes 250 Uranium, and requires explicit Thorium research to unlock.  Do you even have access to Uranium?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek I just performed a quick search over the latest source snapshots and haven't found any way to get thorium, other than producing it in the workshop. Maybe someone will enlighten us on the wiki at some point (or post an answer here).

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, you can also consume Thorium in your Thorium Reactors, so that it has a regular rate of consumption. I haven't actually unlocked that yet, but that's what it says in the tooltip.

Comment: @ChronoD Feel free to edit the answer and add the information :)